# How to fix unknown error for cloning a git url in Slack

Tags: github, slack

I am using slack and configured different git urls. Below error is coming, while this `git-url` is working perfectly fine.

```
flux-system.flux-system
unable to clone '<git_url>', error: unknown error: remote:
```

Please advise how to fix this.

Comment: This was probably a permissions issue. In my case, I got this error trying to clone a private Gitlab project without assigning the correct deployment key to Flux and the project. Assigning the deploy key fixed the error.